# GENERIC_ALL and folder/file ACLs? What does GENERIC_ALL really do?

Tags: c, windows, file-io, createfile

I recently redesigned the security on a file server of ours, marking most of what was Full Control to be Modify.  Now my developers are telling me that whenever they use GENERIC_ALL to open a file (with `CreateFile()` for instance), they receive an access denied message.

After research, nothing seemed to indicate that `GENERIC_ALL` was any more than `GENERIC_EXECUTE` + `GENERIC_WRITE` + `GENERIC_READ`; however, this seems not to be the case, since a developer was able to add the three constant values, and use this to `CreateFile()`.

So, I ask... what does `GENERIC_ALL` really do?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Like some damn ghost in the machine miracle, I thought about this today when I came across a timeout issue with TortoiseHg not being able to create files on a user's share.  Whoever just updated the post, I owe you one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GENERIC_ALL` access rights include *every* possible access right, including such things as `WRITE_DAC` (to change permissions) and `WRITE_OWNER` (to change owner). The [File Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page shows how the `GENERIC_*` access rights map to specific access rights for files. The [File Access Rights Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page shows all the possible access rights for files (which presumably would all be requested when `GENERIC_ALL` is used).

You should encourage your developers to request only the level of access that they actually  need. Rarely, for example, is a file opened for both `GENERIC_EXECUTE` and `GENERIC_WRITE` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`GENERIC_ALL` means "every possible level of access" (for files, this has the name `FILE_ALL_ACCESS`). Since you removed Full Control, attempts to open for `GENERIC_ALL` will fail with Access Denied because (for example) `WRITE_DAC` is no longer granted.