# CreateFile with OPEN_ALWAYS on existing file in OneDrive For Business (OFB) failed as ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, winapi, onedrive, access-denied, createfile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    HANDLE a = CreateFileW((LPCWSTR)u"D:\\OneDrive - 翁悸会\\test2.txt", GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD b = GetLastError();
    std::cout << a << "\n" << b;
}
```

This code can successfully open or create a file anywhere other than my OFB - where, if the file exists, it will return an error code 5, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

This error happens in all subdirectories in the OFB. On the contrary, even my OneDrive Personal will allow this operation. And of course, I have full access to the OFB - I can normally create or open any file with Windows Explorer.

Either if the file does not exist or the file is not in the OFB, CreateFile succeeds.

Is it a windows bug, or I did something wrong?

OS: Win11 22499.1010

OFB: 21.225.1031.0005

Comment: We cannot see whether the call to `CreateFileW` actually fails. You are only supposed to call `GetLastError` in case that call fails, indicated by the return value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. If it does fail, make sure to call `GetLastError` **immediately**, with **absolutely no interleaving code**. The code presented does have interleaving code, and the return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless at that point.

Comment: @IInspectable OK I changed the code. Still the same error code.

Comment: You don't check the return value of CreateFile. Also, that cast is wrong. Remove it.

Comment: The cast is unfortunately required, and correct. That's the mess that `char16_t` and friends got us into.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508679/generic-all-and-folder-file-acls-what-does-generic-all-really-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GENERIC\_ALL and folder/file ACLs? What does GENERIC\_ALL really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508679/generic-all-and-folder-file-acls-what-does-generic-all-really-do)

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes it succeeded using GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE. But why is GENERIC_ALL not allowed only in OFB?

Comment: @埃博拉酱 GENERIC_ALL is not equivalent to GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE.I suggest you could refer to the Blog:[GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170310-00/?p=95705)